# What do I use instead of NetworkBehaviour in mirror API in C# (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

Unity Discontinued HLAPI in 2018 so I am using mirror API, but it is giving an error when I'm using `NetworkBehaviour`. The error that I am getting is `The type or namespace name 'NetworkBehaviour' could not be found`

**Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Behaviour[] componentsToDisable;

    void start()
    {
        if(!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            for(int i=0;i < componentsToDisable.Length;i++)
            {
                componentsToDisable(i).enable=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`using Mirror;`](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/api/Mirror.NetworkBehaviour.html) instead of `using UnityEngine.Networking;`